# Upper bound for number of primes close to the next prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime number and let $g_n := p_{n+1} - p_n$ be the $n$th prime gap. I'm looking for a good upper bound for the quantity
$$G(x, y) :=\#\{p_n \leq x : g_n \leq y\} ,$$
holding uniformly in a reasonable range of $x,y$. In [1] it is proved that
$$\sum_{p_n \leq x} \frac1{g_n} \ll \frac{x \log \log x}{(\log x)^2} ,$$
and multipling this last inequality by $y$ it follows easily that 
$$G(x, y) \ll \frac{x y \log \log x}{(\log x)^2} ,$$
which is non-trivial for $y = o((\log x)^2 / \log \log x)$. However, I bet that much better results are known. Thanks for any reference or suggestion.

[1] *Erdős, P. and Rényi, A., Some problems and results on consecutive primes, Simon Stevin. A Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics 1950*

Comment: When $y = O(1)$ then the bound you derived gives $O(x (\log \log x)(\log x)^{-2})$, which is very close to what's known (for example given by Brun's sieve). Are you asking about how to remove the $\log \log x$ factor in general?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Removing log log x would be good. I agree with your observation on the Brun's sieve, but I'm actually more interested in the case in which $y$ grows with $x$.